# How to get Kafka header's value to Spark Dataset as a single column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

We have a Kafka stream that has headers enabled

```
  .option("includeHeaders", true)
```

thus making them stored as a high level dataset's colum, bearing the inside array of structs with key and value:

```
root
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- headers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

I can access the needed header with it's order in the array like that:

```
val controlDataFrame = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaLocation)
      .option("includeHeaders", true)
      .option("failOnDataLoss", value = false)
      .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
      .load()
      .withColumn("acceptTimestamp", element_at(col("headers"),1))
      .withColumn("acceptTimestamp2", col("acceptTimestamp.value").cast("STRING"))
```

but this solution looks fragile, as the order of headers produced on other side can always be changed with updates, while only thhe key name looks stabile there. How can I lookup through the struct keys and extract the needed struct rather than poin the array index?

UPD.

Thanks to davice of Alex Ott, I have fount the solution to get what I want into the following columns:

```
.withColumn("headers1", map_from_entries(col("headers")))
.withColumn("acceptTimestamp2", col("headers1.acceptTimestamp").cast("STRING"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map_from_entries](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries.html) function to convert an array of structs into a map where you can access entries by name.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map_from_entries

....
select(map_from_entries("headers").alias("headers"), ...)
```

but as I remember, header names may not be unique, that's a primary reason why they are sent as an array of key/value pairs.

Another approach would be to use [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) function to find headers by name - this will allow to handle non-unique headers.

P.S. I have used Python docs because I can link individual functions - it's not easy to do in the Scala docs.